# How to safely update data in Realm from background Worker

Tags: android

There is an large app that uses coroutines to update data in local Realm database. Realm is factored and distributed by Dagger 2. All this happens when using the app in foreground. But now I shall update data from background service (FirebaseMessaging).

How to update realm database with data from Worker in WorkManager that is queued from background service. What is ideal approach that will not lead into deadlocks or any other kind of collisions.

Comment: Did you managed to do it?